# How to implement request.args.get('next')

Tags: python-3.x, http, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to implement a feature i see in social media platforms, in this case, say a user who is not logged in wants to post or leave a comment, a login popup(in my case a modal) appears and they are expected to sign in,(the modal also prompts them to sign up if they don't have an account), then they get redirected to that post in particular and are now able to comment.

Here is my home route view function.

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route("/home",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    posts = Pitch.query.all()
    comments = Comment.query.all()


    registerForm = Register()
    if registerForm.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(registerForm.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username = registerForm.username.data, email = registerForm.email.data, password = hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login!','success')
        mail_message("Welcome to watchlist","templates/email/welcome_user",user.email,user=user)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))


    form = Login()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password,form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('circles'))

        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password','danger')

    return render_template('home.html', title='login',form=form, registerForm=registerForm ,posts=posts, comments=comments)
```

Here is my individual post view function

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def post(post_id):
    review= CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.query.all()
    post = Pitch.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if review.validate_on_submit():
        comment = Comment(body= review.comment.data,post_id=post.id )
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been created!','success')
        return redirect(url_for('post',post_id=post.id))
    return render_template('post.html',title = post.title, post=post,review=review, comments = comments )
```

Here is my home page template snippet:

```html
 {% for post in posts %}
      <div id="homejumbotron" class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            
                <img id="avatar" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/' + post.author.image_file) }}" alt=""
                class="rounded-circle col-md-2">
            
            <div id="postintro" class="col-md-10 ">
                <a id="authorname" href="#" class="row mr-2">{{post.author.username}}</a>
              <small class="text-muted row" id="date">
                {{post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}
              </small>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
          <hr>
          
          <a id="title" href="{{url_for('post',post_id=post.id)}}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        <div class="footer">
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p> 
        </div>
        <hr>
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{{url_for('post',post_id=post.id)}}"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i><small>Leave review</small></i></a> 
            {% else %}
    <!--if not authenticated,pop up login modal,then redirect back to the post you were trying to view-->
         <a href="{{url_for('post',post_id=post.id)}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLoginForm"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i><small>Leave review</small></i></a> 
   
            {% endif %}
      </div>
      {%endfor%}
```

what it does currently is redirect to my circles template directly since the modal forms submission redirects to circles template.. Any suggestions on how this can be implemented?